# Why doesn't my Linux superuser root directory ls command show all files?

Tags: linux

If I log in and then head to my superuser root via:

```
sudo su -
```

I'm now in the root directory. I can display a list of files and directories via `ls`. However quite a few directories don't seem to be there. For example, I can:

```
cd /svr/www
```

and end up in the directory `www`. The `svr` directory is not shown when I type the `ls` command from root, nor does it appear to be under any of the directories that are shown.

What am I missing?

Comment: What specific flavor of "Unix" is this? Is this the real System V from the 1970s, or are you using some derivative like, oh I don't know, Linux or BSD? Please call it by what it really is and not some generalized term like "Unix".

Comment: Changed to Linux. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: After you `sudo su -` do you `cd` to any other directory or is the first command you are typing `ls` ?

Answer (score 7):

After the command `sudo su -` I think you will find you are in root's home directory `/root` not in the root directory `/`. Hence `ls` will not show `/srv`. I suggest you use `pwd` to check which folder you are in.

Comment: @allquixotic (and others) From the OP's response this was **not** a duplicate of the previous question!

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the `/` directory and type `ls`, you will **not** see "recursive" subdirectories. You will only see directories that are direct children of the current directory. So in order to see `/srv/www` you would have to first `cd /srv` and then `ls`.

There's a such thing as recursive `ls`; however, if you need the full paths, `find` is a better alternative.

See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767384/ls-command-how-can-i-get-a-recursive-full-path-listing-one-line-per-file) which has treated the subject matter of recursive file/directory listing already.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the above question. I meant that 'svr' is not shown under root.

Comment: Are you not seeing it from the `#` (root) shell, or from the `$` shell? Permissions could be set such that only the root user can see the directory... for example, `chmod o-x /` could do this (if `/` is not executable).

Comment: # shell. What's the difference between # and $ shell as root?

Comment: `#` is the root shell. If you are "logged in" as root, your shell will be `#`. If you are logged in as a regular user, your shell will be `$`. Root shouldn't suffer from **any** discretionary access control permission limitations whatsoever, which means that `chmod` and `chown` and similar permissions on directories/files should be ignored, and should not be a cause of seeing behavior like this.

Comment: One additional thing you can try is `ls -la` -- the additional command line options will show e.g. hidden files as well... although normally the only hidden files are those that begin with a dot `.` character; those are always hidden from the regular `ls` command.

Comment: So in that case going back to my original question, why wouldn't /svr show up when I type ls in root shell?

Comment: Someone else has encountered this situation, and it turned out to be filesystem corruption! Please see the "possible duplicate" I posted as a comment to the question. People also list a *ton* of debugging techniques within that question that provide even more possible ways that this could go wrong, including things like `LS_OPTIONS` and on and on. Check it out!